# Scala case class to Spring POJO

Tags: java, spring, scala, spray

In my current project, I am trying to migrate a Java project (REST-based backend) into a Scala project using the Spray framework. Our plan is to keep same our data base layer in Java where we are using Spring with MyBatis. But the business logic and request/response handling will be done by Spray. Can anyone suggest, after implementing the business logic on API call how can I convert/transport those case class into JAVA POJO?

Same thing will be required after getting data back from DB. On that case, after getting the result from DB (which is in Java) we have to transfer back those Java POJO into Scala (to reply back to a client). Can any one provide any suggestion or way out to do this kind of back and forth of an object between Scala to Java and Java to Scala?

Comment: DO NOT migrate to spray - it is no logger actively developed nor maintained. Use akka-http instead.

Comment: okey ....I did not know ... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest separating your data layer model and business logic model, even if Objects fields are the same. 
Write converters manually for all your case classes and POJOs.
Yes, it is time-consuming and needs a lot of boilerplate code, but you layers models will be independent (as they should be). 
Move those conversion methods to separate object or package object. 
DB to BL conversion could be transferred to case class apply method, but not vice versa